# Clip raster to certain pixel size in multiple mannualy selected locations in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, clip

I want to manually select and clip several areas in a raster layer and get the outcome of a certain size in pixels (e.g. 500x500px).

I would approach it with first creating polygon shapefiles over the areas of interest and then clip raster by mask layer.

I got stuck because I can't figure out how to create a polygon of a certain size in pixels (corresponding to the raster layer).

Or is there any better way to approach this problem? I am happy to switch to Python for some of the processing but I need to select the areas of interest manually on the map.

Comment: If you know the raster corners and row/col count or one corner, rotation and pixel dimensions you can use basic trig to construct the polygon. Please [Edit] the Question to state what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: If the raster isnt to big you can [vectorize](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgispixelstopolygons) it, select a number of pixels, merge and use as clip feature. But it will be a bit tricky to select 500 pixels

Comment: Are all your polygons rectangles aligned with the raster?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Vince, do you mean that I should first cut a sample raster to 500x500px and then construct a polygon based on its data? Could you share what you mean with basic trig, I am pretty new to GIS...

Answer (score 1):

Your best option might be `gdal_translate` using the `-srcwin` option. With that option you can set the offset (in row-column) and the size (in pixels) to subset the input raster. But you will need the image coordinates (**not** real world coordinates) of the clipping polygon.

If you want to use, instead, the `-projwin` option, then you'll need to calculate the real world, projected, coordinates based on <image resolution X 500>, in order to get your desired 500x500 pixel window.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! With this approach though I would not be able to visually inspect which area will be cut, correct? It would be helpful to see and adjust the area to be clipped in Qgis beforehand.